# Mounting ext2 sdcard partition causes I/O errors

Tags: mount, partitions, ext2

So I am attempting to mount an ext2 partition on a pen drive to a tablet I have, the actually mount is done with:

```
adb shell "mount -t ext2 /dev/block/sdb /mnt/ubuntu"
```

This works fine and ubuntu is a folder I already created on the android device.
Now when I go to access the files on that partition (the rootfs of a ubuntu install in fact) I end up with:

```
root@android:/ # ls /storage/ubuntu
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/android' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/bin' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/boot' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/dev' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/etc' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/external_sd' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/home' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/lib' failed: I/O error
lost+found
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/media' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/mnt' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/opt' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/proc' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/root' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/run' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/sbin' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/sdcard' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/selinux' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/srv' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/sys' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/tmp' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/usr' failed: I/O error
lstat '/storage/ubuntu/var' failed: I/O error
```

Comment: This doesn't look quite right. You say you mounted the partition at `/mnt/ubuntu` but you're trying to list `/storage/ubuntu`.

Comment: Funny thing is that it still finds Ubuntu specific entries there. Sure it's an ext2 filesystem? That's not used with Ubuntu since... well, for years (currently they use ext4 by default). And I never heard Ubuntu has an `external_sd` folder in its root fs. Could it be you tried mounting that into a mount point already in use (thus mixing things up)?

Comment: DanHulme yes sorry ls for /mnt/ubuntu is what I am using, @Izzy it is actually listing all the root folders that should be there (some are not actually from the stock rootfs rather stuff i added)

Comment: So just to make sure: that `external_sd` folder really exists in the root of your Ubuntu disk? And the file system on that disk really is ext2?